# d3.js data array if statement

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I am trying to cancel out rows that have y value > 5000.
Here is graph with all data from csv file:

http://dtech.id.lv/d3/origin.html

And here is my attempt to modify forEach function with if statement:

http://dtech.id.lv/d3/modif.html

```
// Get the data
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {

            if (d.close < 5000) {
                less5000++;
      d.close = +d.close;
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            }
    if (d.close > 5000) {
                over5000++;
            }

    total++;

        });
```

Something isn't right here and I cant figure out how to write this properly.
Can someone please point me to correct way of doing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is somewhere else:

Several of your data entries have wrong date format, so `x(d.date)` in your valueline method returns NaN, which can't be displayed and d3 crashes (see your JS console at http://dtech.id.lv/d3/modif.html).

That is how your first data entry looks like, which is fine: `{dd: "2016-03-13", date: Mon Jan 01 1900 00:00:03 GMT+0100 (CET), close: 131}`

... and this is how an invalid one in your data set looks like: `{dd: "2016-03-13", date: "10:54:43", close: "10465"}`

There are about 20 data entries which have invalid date objects in you data.csv

**UPDATE**

Behavior above is because, you do not parse d.date if d.close is 5000 or more. Update your code to

```
// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
     data.forEach(function(d) {
         if (d.close < 5000) {
              less5000++;
         }
         if (d.close > 5000) {
              over5000++;
         }

         d.close = +d.close;
         d.date = parseDate(d.date);

         total++;
     });
...
```

**UPDATE 2**

To filter your array use *array*.filter (see: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays)!
In your case:

```
// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
     data = data.filter(function(d){
          d.close = +d.close;
          d.date = parseDate(d.date);

          return d.close < 5000;
     });
...
```

data will only contain entries which have d.close smaller then 5000.

Comment: But how come?
Entry's are formatted the same... 

2016-03-13,00:00:03,131,26,34.43

2016-03-13,10:54:43,10465,26,0.43

Comment: Ohh, took me a while, but i found the error. You are not parsing the date, if d.close is 5000 or more. I'm gonna update my answer.

Comment: Main goal is to cancel out d.close values over 5000, so that graph contains  only d.close values < 5000. I cant figure how to cancel them out.

Comment: In that case, simply use js/d3 filter (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays), e.g.: ```data = data.filter(function(d){return d.close < 5000});``` and get rid of the forEach.